# Default menu missing in my eclipse RCP project

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I I build a eclipse RCP application via the new plug-in project wizard(with perspective). Then I run the application, and only some of the default menus showed, see the screenshot below. I want them all. Can anyone he me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svmwd.png)

I especially want the "Open projects from file system" item. I browsed the internet and found one possible solution, but I cannot achieve my goal. The solution is, add Action in `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java`, using `ActionFactory.*`. But I counldn't find `ActionFactory.OPEN_PROJECT` or anything like that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ActionFactory for this. "Open projects from file system" is contributed to the File menu by the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point:

```xml
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:file?after=new.ext">
         <command
               commandId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.importer.openDirectory"
               id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.importer.openDirectory.menu"
               mnemonic="%importProjectsFromFolder_mnemonic"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
```

That says that the menu item is added to the file menu after a placeholder called `new.ext` (and will not be added if that is not there).

You can added the correct placeholder in the ActionBarAdvisor class using

```java
menu.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.NEW_EXT));
```

where `menu` is the menu manager for the File menu.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can add all default menus and menu items? As you can see, I only have four of the menus, and the menu items are very few.

Comment: If you have your own ActionBarAdvisor you have to add everything you want to that. You can look at the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` that Eclipse uses to see everything that Eclipse uses.

Comment: Note that if you just want to add a few things to a full Eclipse then building the RCP from scratch is not the right thing to do - write plug-ins to add to Eclipse and optionally a branding plug-in to change the product name. There are several different approaches depending on what you want to end up with.

Comment: Thank you. I actually already have a plugin project, and I want to export it so it can be an RCP. So I guess, I just want to add a few things to a full Eclipse. But I tried to build a product file and then export it, but I failed. So I am now trying to build an empty RCP project and add things into it.

Comment: The full Eclipse requires lots of things to be initialized properly, this is hard to do starting from an empty RCP.